# How to copy attachment feature class from personal GDB to File GDB?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, file-geodatabase, personal-geodatabase, attachments

I have some feature classes with attachments in personal geodatabase  . I want to copy these  from personal to file geodatabase automatically using arcpy. I used [the code](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156708/copying-feature-classes-from-personal-geodatabase-to-file-geodatabase-using-arcp) suggested by @Aaron to copy all feautre classes and datasets to file geodatabase.It was great But i couldn't copy attachments using the code.How can i copy the attachments to file gdb using arcpy?

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have assumed following:

1. For your feature-classes in  mdb, "_ATTACH" suffix is used for only attachment table.
2. You can further customize this code.
3. This code needs to be run after all featureclasses (**except attachment tables- this script will create attachment table and load relationship classes from the respective table from the mdb into gdb**) are moved from mdb to gdb .
4. It is tested in arcmap 10.3.

   ```
   mdb_folder = r'C:\Users\USER_NAME\Documents\ArcGIS\gissta'
   gdb_folder = r'C:\Users\USER_NAME\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb'


   tables_paths = []
   tables_names = []
   #get all attachement tables in the mdb. 
   for w,d,f in arcpy.da.Walk(mdb_folder):
       for i in f:
           if i.endswith("__ATTACH"):
               tables_names.append(i)
               tables_paths.append(os.path.join(w,i))


   #get all featureclasses have attachment tables in the **gdb** then create those tables in gdb and load data in them. 
   for w,d,f in arcpy.da.Walk(gdb_folder):
       for i in f:
           if i in [j.replace("__ATTACH","") for j in tables_names]:
               pth = os.path.join(w,i)
               arcpy.EnableAttachments_management(in_dataset=pth)
               tbl = pth+"__ATTACH"
               for k in tables_paths:
                   print k
                   if i in k:
                       arcpy.Append_management(inputs=k, target=tbl, schema_type="TEST", field_mapping="", subtype="")
   ```

Comment: Do you have any updates? If i have been of use in your help.